# ¿Cómo mostrar en pantalla solo los archivos de noviembre y diciembre para luego hacerle un grep?

Tags: linux, bash, date, shell, grep

Estoy tratando de mostrar en pantalla archivos de noviembre y diciembre para luego buscar un patrón con grep en el contenido de estos archivos.

Comment: Para poder ayudarte deberías mostrar el listado de archivos y cómo se va a identificar los archivos y si has intantado algo hasta ahora.

Comment: Colega, ese texto es muy corto para ser una pregunta y muy largo para ser una búsqueda de Google.

Answer (score 4):

Puedes utilizar el comando `find` con los flags:

- `-type f`: para indicar que buscas archivos.
- `-newermt '<fecha>'`: que es `-newerXY` y donde XY son `m` (que es la fecha de modificacion) y `t` (que es la fecha interpretada por `date` con su argumento `-d`).
- `-not -newermt '<fecha>'`: para negar un rango de fecha.

Para el caso específico de noviembre y diciembre, puedes utilizar esto (suponiendo que conoces el año):

```
$ find . -type f -newermt '01-nov-2019 -1 sec' -not -newermt '01-jan-2020'
```

Pero es porque los meses son contiguos. En casos de fechas no contiguas podría utilizar algo diferente.

```
$ \ls -l | egrep "Nov|Mar" | awk '{print $9}'
```

Suponiendo que los meses son Noviembre y Marzo.

Esta solución no es robusta, pero puede funcionar según el caso.

Después de haber encontrado los archivos, podrías utilizar `xargs` y luego `grep` (esto en lugar del `cat` y `grep` que mencionaste en tu pregunta, y que a mi consideración son innecesarios).

Por ejemplo, para el primer caso:

```
$ find . -type f -newermt '01-nov-2019 -1 sec' -not -newermt '01-jan-2020' | xargs grep "<palabra a buscar>"
```

Para el segundo:

```
$ \ls -l | egrep "Nov|Mar" | awk '{print $9}' | xargs grep "<palabra a buscar>"
```

Comment: ¡Gran respuesta! No conocía `newermt` de `find`.

Comment: ¡Si! `newerXY` es bastante poderoso y cómodo. Hacen que `find` sea todavía más seductor.

Comment: Se puede hacer un du -sh de eso que se imprime en pantalla?

Comment: @JesusHenriquez No entiendo tu pregunta. Se pueden hacer muchas cosas con `xargs`.

Comment: La idea es utilizar esos nombres de archivos pero sacarle un du -sh de cada archivo resultante

Comment: Es decir du -sh (archivo o carpeta de noviembre y diciembre), algo por el estilo

Comment: Puedes hacer eso con `xargs` usando `du -h` en lugar de `grep`, después de `xargs`. De todas maneras, para que te pueda ayudar con más precisión, sería bueno que lo pusieras en tu pregunta en lugar de las aclaraciones dentro de una respuesta. Una vez que hagas la prueba se te podría ayudar con las nuevas dudas que surjan.